# Does a series have to start from 1 to be able to apply convergence tests?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

In the ratio test, for example, we know that the test applies for a sum from n=1 to n=infinity.

Can I directly apply this test to sums from n=x to n=infinity (for example, a sum from n=0 -> infinity)?

Comment: You can start **anywhere**.

Comment: The behavior of finitely many terms never affects convergence of sums like this, so the fact that the index starts at $0$ rather than $1$ is irrelevant in applying the test.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. As we get infinitely many terms, a couple terms at the front end will make no difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can always write your sum as a sum starting with the index $1$ by performing an index shift:
$$
\sum_{k=k_0}^\infty a_k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{k_0+k-1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Studying the nature of a series means proving if a series converges or diverges. The series sums from n=1 to n=infinity and sums from n=x to n=infinity have the same nature, so the test can be made for any of the series. That is so because finitely terms of the series do not change the nature of the series.

Answer (score 0):

> The behavior of finitely many terms never affects convergence of sums like this, so the fact that the index starts at 0 rather than 1 is irrelevant in applying the test.